# Trying to convert a postscribe function to normal JS or jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom, dom-manipulation

Is there any way to convert this postscribe function to normal JS or jQuery?

```
postscribe('#coding-block', "<script class='gist-code' src='" + gistObject['embed_url'] + "'><\/script>");
```

I tried these but none of them work:

```
document.getElementById("coding-block").innerHTML = "<script class='gist-code' src='" + gistObject['embed_url'] + "'><\/script>";


document.getElementById("coding-block").write("<script class='gist-code' src='" + gistObject['embed_url'] + "'><\/script>");


document.getElementById("coding-block").textContent = "<script class='gist-code' src='" + gistObject['embed_url'] + "'><\/script>";
```

**EDIT:**

Just adding the executable code snippet to the post:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">

    <title>Guess the coding language</title>
    <meta name="description" content="The HTML5 Herald">
    <meta name="author" content="SitePoint">

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/styles.css?v=1.0">
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Nunito:wght@200;300;400;600;700;800;900&display=swap"
        rel="stylesheet">
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/axios/dist/axios.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/postscribe/2.0.8/postscribe.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://code.iconify.design/1/1.0.6/iconify.min.js"></script>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

    <style>
        body {
            display: flex;
            justify-content: center;
            font-family: Nunito;
            background: linear-gradient(146.11deg, #FFDFBA 20.43%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0) 79.91%), linear-gradient(202.81deg, #FF6636 38.99%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0) 85.2%), #FFB45C;
        }

        @keyframes gradient {
            0% {
                background-position: 0% 50%;
            }

            50% {
                background-position: 100% 50%;
            }

            100% {
                background-position: 0% 50%;
            }
        }

        .main-container {
            max-width: 700px;
            width: 100%;
            margin: auto;
        }

        .points-container {
            margin: auto;
            text-align: center;
        }

        .top-score-value {
            font-size: 72px;
            font-weight: 800;
            margin: 0;
        }

        .top-score-title {
            margin-top: -10px;
            font-size: 24px;
            font-weight: 800;
        }

        #coding-container {
            margin-top: 40px;
            font-size: 20px;
        }

        .question {
            margin-bottom: 10px;
        }

        #coding-block {
            overflow: auto;
            max-height: 500px;
        }

        .gist-meta {
            display: none;
        }

        .answers-container {
            margin: 20px;
            display: grid;
            grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr;
            grid-gap: 1em;
        }

        .btn-general {
            border: none;
            background: transparent;
            background-color: white;
            border-radius: 100px;
            outline: none;
            font-weight: 800;
            font-family: Nunito;
            height: 65px;
            -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 10px 20px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15);
            box-shadow: 0px 10px 20px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15);
        }

        .btn-success {
            background: linear-gradient(119.32deg, #7BFF2A 16.26%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0) 67.98%), #59EB00;
            box-shadow: 0px 1px 20px rgba(99, 255, 105, 0.7);
            color: white;
        }

        .btn-fail {
            background: linear-gradient(109.45deg, #FF7373 -7.86%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0) 79.2%), #FF4949;
            box-shadow: 0px 1px 20px #FF7B7B;
            color: white;
        }

        .bottom-container {
            display: grid;
            grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr;
            grid-gap: 1em;
            margin: 20px;
            align-items: center;
        }

        .final-score-title {
            font-weight: 600;
        }

        .final-score-value {
            font-weight: 800;
        }

        .end-text {
            font-weight: 600;
            color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
            margin-top: 10px;
            margin-bottom: 10px;
        }

        .btn-retry {
            position: relative;
        }

        .iconify {
            position: absolute;
            right: 35px;
            top: 22px;
        }

        @media only screen and (max-width: 768px) {
            #coding-block {
                max-height: 300px;
            }

            .question {
                font-size: 18px;
            }

            .answers-container {
                grid-template-columns: 1fr;
                margin: 0;
                margin-top: 20px;
            }

            .btn-general {
                height: 55px;
            }

            .bottom-container {
                grid-template-columns: 1fr;
                grid-gap: 0;
                margin: 0;
                margin-top: 30px;
                text-align: center;
            }

            .end-text {
                margin: 0;
            }

            .iconify {
                position: absolute;
                right: 35px;
                top: 22px;
            }

            .btn-retry {
                position: absolute;
                width: 100%;
                bottom: 0;
                left: 0;
            }

            .btn-general {
                height: 55px;
                width: 100%;
            }

            .bottom-container {
                display: block;
                position: relative;
            }
        }



        .hide {
            visibility: hidden;
        }

        .disable {
            pointer-events: none;
        }

        .lds-ripple {
            display: inline-block;
            position: relative;
            width: 80px;
            height: 80px;
        }

        .lds-ripple div {
            position: absolute;
            border: 4px solid #fff;
            opacity: 1;
            border-radius: 50%;
            animation: lds-ripple 1s cubic-bezier(0, 0.2, 0.8, 1) infinite;
        }

        .lds-ripple div:nth-child(2) {
            animation-delay: -0.5s;
        }

        @keyframes lds-ripple {
            0% {
                top: 36px;
                left: 36px;
                width: 0;
                height: 0;
                opacity: 1;
            }

            100% {
                top: 0px;
                left: 0px;
                width: 72px;
                height: 72px;
                opacity: 0;
            }
        }
    </style>

</head>

<body>
    <div class="main-container">
        <div class="points-container">
            <h1 class="top-score-value">0</h1>
            <h3 class="top-score-title">Points</h3>
        </div>
        <div id="coding-container">
            <h3 class="question">Which programming language is this?</h3>
            <div class="lds-ripple">
                <div></div>
                <div></div>
            </div>
            <div id="coding-block">

            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="answers-container">
            <button class="btn-general btn-answers btn0"></button>
            <button class="btn-general btn-answers btn1"></button>
            <button class="btn-general btn-answers btn2"></button>
            <button class="btn-general btn-answers btn3"></button>
        </div>
        <div class="bottom-container">
            <div class="final-score-container">
                <span class="final-score-title">Final score: </span>
                <span class="final-score-value">0 Points</span>
                <p class="end-text"> Take a screenshot and send it to us :)</p>
            </div>
            <button class="btn-general btn-next">Next</button>
            <button class="btn-general btn-retry">Retry<span class="iconify" data-inline="false"
                    data-icon="akar-icons:arrow-right" style="font-size: 22px;"></span></button>
        </div>
    </div>

    <script>
        var gistObjectArray;
        var gistIndex = 0;
        var randomLanguages = ["Swift", "JavaScript", "Java", "Kotlin", "Shell", "PowerShell", "C++", "C", "C#", "Ruby", "Dart", "Python", "Objective-C", "Perl", "Go", "PHP", "R", "Dockerfile", "CSS", "HTML", "TypeScript", "Haskell", "GLSL"];
        var rightLanguage;
        var rightNumberIndex;
        var points = 0;

        $(document).ready(function () {
            clearButtons();
            fetchGists();

            //button clicks
            $(".btn-answers").click(function (event) {
                let chosenLanguage = $(event.target).text();
                if (chosenLanguage == rightLanguage) {
                    showSuccessUI(event.target);
                } else {
                    showFailUI(event.target);
                }
            });

            $(".btn-next").click(function (event) {
                gistIndex += 1;
                refreshUI();
            });

            $(".btn-retry").click(function (event) {
                gistIndex += 1;
                points = 0;
                refreshUI();
            });

        });

        const client = axios.create({
            auth: {
                username: "shubhamgarg",
                password: "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"
            },
            headers: {
                "Accept": "application/vnd.github.v3+json"
            }
        });

        var fetchCount = 0;
        function fetchGists() {
            let random = getRandomInt(100);

            client.get('https://api.github.com/gists/public?page=' + random)
                .then(function (response) {
                    let gistArrayJson = response["data"];
                    gistObjectArray = findBestGists(gistArrayJson);
                    if (gistObjectArray == null) {
                        fetchGists();
                    }
                    else {
                        resetVariables();
                        //console.log(gistObjectArray)
                        refreshUI()
                    }
                })
                .catch(function (error) {
                    // handle error
                    console.log(error);
                })
        }

        function resetVariables() {
            gistIndex = 0;
            rightLanguage = null;
            rightNumberIndex = null;
        }

        function refreshUI() {
            clearButtons();

            if (gistIndex == gistObjectArray.length) {
                fetchGists();
                return;
            }

            let gistObject = gistObjectArray[gistIndex];
            rightLanguage = gistObject["language"];

            let randomAnswers = [];
            while (randomAnswers.length != 4) {
                var randomAns = randomLanguages[getRandomInt(randomLanguages.length - 1)];
                if (!randomAnswers.includes(randomAns) && randomAns != rightLanguage) {
                    randomAnswers.push(randomAns);
                }
            }

            rightNumberIndex = getRandomInt(randomAnswers.length - 1);
            randomAnswers[rightNumberIndex] = rightLanguage;

            for (var i = 0; i < randomAnswers.length; i++) {
                $(".btn" + i).text(randomAnswers[i]);
            }

            $("#coding-block").empty();
            $(".lds-ripple").css("display", "none");
            // document.getElementById("coding-block").write("<script class='gist-code' src='" + gistObject['embed_url'] + "'><\/script>");
            // document.getElementById("coding-block").innerHTML= "<scr"+"ipt class= 'gist-code' src='"+ gistObject['embed_url'] + "'><\/scr"+"ipt>";
            postscribe('#coding-block', "<script class='gist-code' src='" + gistObject['embed_url'] + "'><\/script>");
            // let posstscribe = document.createElement('script');
            // posstscribe.classList.add('src', 'gist-code');
            // posstscribe.setAttribute('src', gistObject['embed_url']);
            // document.querySelector('#coding-block').appendChild(posstscribe);

        }

        function clearButtons() {
            $(".btn-answers").removeClass("btn-success");
            $(".btn-answers").removeClass("btn-fail");
            $(".btn-answers").removeClass("disable");

            $(".bottom-container").addClass("hide");
            $(".bottom-container").addClass("hide");
            $(".btn-next").addClass("hide");
            $(".btn-retry").addClass("hide");
            $(".final-score-container").addClass("hide");
            $(".top-score-value").text(points);
            $(".final-score-value").text(points + " Points");
        }

        function showSuccessUI(buttonTapped) {
            $(buttonTapped).addClass("btn-success");
            points += 50;
            $(".top-score-value").text(points);
            $(".bottom-container").removeClass("hide");
            $(".btn-next").removeClass("hide");
            $(".btn-retry").addClass("hide");
            $(".final-score-container").addClass("hide");
            $(".btn-answers").addClass("disable");

        }

        function showFailUI(buttonTapped) {
            $(buttonTapped).addClass("btn-fail");
            $(".btn" + rightNumberIndex).addClass("btn-success");
            $(".final-score-value").text(points + " Points");

            $(".bottom-container").removeClass("hide");
            $(".btn-next").addClass("hide");
            $(".btn-retry").removeClass("hide");
            $(".final-score-container").removeClass("hide");
            $(".btn-answers").addClass("disable");
        }

        function findBestGists(gistArrayJson) {
            //gistArrayJson is an array of dictionaries
            var gistObjectArray = []
            for (var i = 0; i < gistArrayJson.length; i++) {
                let gistJson = gistArrayJson[i];
                let htmlUrl = gistJson["html_url"];

                let files = gistJson["files"];
                let firstFile = files[Object.keys(files)[0]];
                let secondFile = files[Object.keys(files)[1]];

                if (firstFile == undefined || secondFile != undefined) {
                    continue;
                }

                let size = firstFile["size"];
                let language = firstFile["language"];

                if (!isValidLanguage(language)) {
                    continue;
                } else {
                    var gistObject = {};
                    gistObject["embed_url"] = htmlUrl + ".js";
                    gistObject["language"] = language;
                    gistObjectArray.push(gistObject);
                }
            }

            if (gistObjectArray.length != 0) {
                return gistObjectArray;
            } else {
                return null;
            }
        }

        function isValidLanguage(language) {
            switch (language) {
                case null:
                case "Markdown":
                case "JSON":
                case "Text":
                case "Ignore List":
                case "XML":
                case "Jupyter Notebook":
                case "CSV":
                case "Maven POM":
                case "YAML":
                case "AutoHotkey":
                case "TSV":
                case "reStructuredText":
                case "VCL":
                case "Diff":
                case "TeX":
                case "TOML":
                case "Windows Registry Entries":
                case "SVG":
                case "Ballerina":
                case "Org":

                    return false
                default:
                    return true
            }
        }

        function getRandomInt(max) {
            return Math.floor(Math.random() * Math.floor(max));
        }
    </script>
</body>

</html>
```

If you copy-paste this code to a code editor, the line that has postscribe (which I am trying to change) is line 392. Thanks.

Comment: Try using append for last two.

Comment: @Nithin-Techidiots Yes, it does not work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
let postscribe = document.createElement('script');
postscribe.classList.add('src', 'gist-code');
postscribe.setAttribute('src', gistObject['embed_url']);
document.querySelector('#coding-block').appendChild(postscribe);
```

Comment: Thanks, this is a good approach (i didn't think about it this way) but unfortunately, it does not work for the code. Also, a small correction that I'd like to mention is that src is not a class name @Kinglish